# One click - two functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing a site for a kiosk, so the site goes like a photoslide in-between each div.

I put a layover/mask on the first page, and the layover/mask is removed on a mouse click function at the moment. (As a side note this is for the purpose of hiding the address bar on the first screen for the kiosk as the first page/div is an a tag)

```
 $("#item1").append('<div id="pageLayover"></div>');
 $(document).click(function(){ 
     $("#pageLayover").remove(); 
});
```

Everytime you click your mouse to remove the layover then you need to click another time  then the first a tag page will slide to the second page.

Is there any way I can have one click only not two to remove layover/mask and to let first page to slide to the second page at the same time?

Here is my code on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EXfnN/41/)   Any code/links/examples would be great help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's something I don't quite get: you remove the layover at the mousemove, so how could anyone click on something on the layover if it is removed at the mouse move?

Comment: Hi Hugo, thanks for your response, I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to do a remove and trigger click event at the same time for the first page which is an a tag. Do you think it is not possible? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very confusing, but maybe this is the answer you're looking for:

To make the click on the layover in fact two clicks, you can simply trigger the click event of the first panel:

```
$('#pageLayover').live('click', function(e) { // <-- updated!
  $("#pageLayover").remove(); // remove our layover from the DOM
  $panels.eq(0).click(); // <-- trigger click event of 1st element of $panels
});
```

This does not check if the click occurred on the panel though.

---

You can solve the problem with the multiple layovers with this:

```
$('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800,{
    onAfter: function(id){
        if ($('#pageLayover').length == 0) {             // <--- new
            $("#item1").append('<div id="pageLayover"></div>');
        }                                                // <--- new
```

Comment: Hi Niko, thanks for your response. Sorry i was confused when I wrote the question. Your code is making the function I'm after, thank you, just one little problem if you put the code in http://jsfiddle.net/EXfnN/41/ and run, the first page function works like a charm, but you can click on the third page now and it will go back to the second page instead of first page. Can i still keep the third page not clickable and it goes back to the first page automatically? Thanks very much!

Comment: @SamIAm I've updated the first line of my code. You're code does unfortunately create to many layovers while scrolling, I think you will need to take a deeper look into that to resolve this.

Comment: @SamIAm See http://jsfiddle.net/EXfnN/44/ - is this, how I want it? The other problem I mentioned is, that you can in fact click outside the dark gray area if you're on the first page and still get forwarded to the second page.

Comment: thanks very much for your great help, that is exactly what I'm after, thank you! I see what you mean by the other problem, I've got three little questions if you could help. 1)Is there any way we can fix the other problem easily? 2) Can you please explain the first line a bit eg why are you using live()? 3) What do you mean by 'I create to many layovers while scrolling'? How can I tell and can it cause problems? Sorry Niko, I'm trying to learn from you. Thanks very much!

Comment: Sure, you're very welcome! 1) Every callback function that you hand over to bind(), click(), live() etc. gets an event object as the first parameter. This object has two properties pageX and pageY, giving the coordinates of the click. `$panels.eq(0).offset()` gives you the coordinates of the first panel, so you can check manually if the cursor is over the panel. 2) live() is just the same as bind() or click(), but binds the specified function not only to currently present objects with id #pageLayover, but to all future objects as well. 3) You were (!) creating a new layover after scrolling.

Comment: Thanks Niko, I'll have a proper try and learn what you wrote above slightly later on today for sure, you've been great help to me, thank you!